# Updating a field value in database via submit handler doesn't update the user profile in UI

Tags: forms, database

I've created the field "Attending" that is attached to the user profile.
I have created a form with one checkbox element; when submitted, I've confirmed that the attending_fielddatabase is being updated with the current value (0 or 1), but when I view the user profile through the UI, the updated value isn't being displayed.

The submit handler I am using is the following:

```
function rsvp_aform_submit($form, &$form_state) {
  global $user;
  db_query("UPDATE {field_data_field_attending} SET field_attending_value = :val WHERE entity_id = :eid", array(':val' => $form_state['values']['rsvp'], ':eid' => $user->uid));
  drupal_set_message(t('Your form has been saved.'));
}
```

Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that's the caching. First try to clear the cache manually. If that helps you should use [cache_clear_all()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--cache.inc/function/cache_clear_all/6) to clear the corresponding cache tables (e.g. cache_content, cache_views_data) after you update the db.

Comment: Hah! I thought I was done getting blindsided by caching... thanks so much. I'll upvote when I have the reputation

Comment: In fact, what worked for me was drupal_flush_all_caches().

Comment: ok, but it's a little overkill to clear all caches and rebuild the theme_registry every time this form is submitted. thats simply not necessary and could result in performance shortage.

Comment: Hmm.. I'll need to dig into it then - cache_clear_all() didn't do the trick..

Comment: have you passed the $table parameter? check which cache table you need to clear. maybe just take a look inside your db to find the guilty ones and try. take a look at api for more info on how to use cache_clear_all().

Comment: field_cache_clear() seems to do the trick (for what I assume is a more slight performance hit)